# Objective c i want to hide my navigationbar but i want to show navigationItem's rightBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationitem

i am new in objective-c .I am trying to  hide navigationbar i used this code and it's work perfectly but problem is this when i hide navigationbar after i am failed to show navigationItem's rightBarButtonItem

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
   // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;

}
```

i am used this code for navigationItem

```
-(void)loadBackButton{
     /*UIBarButtonSystemItemDone */
     buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismiss:)];
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;

}

- (void)dismiss:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Dismis Done");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //[self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

and my `- (void)viewDidLoad` are bellow

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     //for load navigationItem's 
    [self loadBackButton];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Comment: You can't see "rightBarButtonItem" but it is inside your Navigation bar

Comment: i hide my Navigation bar ..i just want to show my rightBarButtonItem.. i don't need Navigation bar

Comment: This question makes no sense. You have put buttons on navigation bar and then if you hide the navigation bar what do you think will happen to the buttons? They will be hidden as well as they are on navigation bar. This is not rocket science.

Comment: Why dont you make it transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiding NavigationBar will hide your `rightBarButtonItem` too. One of the possible solutions is that you make the Navigation Bar transparent. You can use following code to do so:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```